Parameter NO_PARAM in request is invalid. Please provide correct value for parameter NO_PARAM (コード: UserErrorInvalidRequestParameter)
I tried to deploy the ARM template of VM backup but I got an error.
The error message was like below and I don't know what should I do.
Parameter NO_PARAM in request is invalid. Please provide correct value for parameter NO_PARAM (コード: UserErrorInvalidRequestParameter)
Here is the template.json and parameter.json.
The template is very simple but I am new to deploy ARM so I don't have any idea what does mean that error.
template.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env":{
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
        "resouceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "VMresouceGroupName": "rg-nonprod-japan-n01-test",
        "VMBackupSettings": {
            "dev": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01d",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2d"
            },
            "qa": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01t",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2t"
            },
            "stg": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01s",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2s"

            },
            "prod": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01p",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-nap-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2p"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        //bkup関連のここだけ別リソースグループへのデプロイ
        {
            "name": "[concat(variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupVaultName, '/Azure/vm;', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupItemName, ';', variables('resouceGroupName'),';', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
            "properties": {
                "friendlyName": "[concat(variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, 'BackupIntent')]",
                "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
                "policyId": "[concat('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies/', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupVaultName, '/EnhancedPolicy')]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(variables('subscriptionId'), variables('VMresouceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
            }
        }
    ]
}

patrameter.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env": {
            "value": "dev"
        }
    }
}

Anyone knows how to solve this error? Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.

HI @CuteeeeRabbit, In your template.json file   VMreosurceGroupName is misspelled (it should be VMResourceGroupName). This could lead to incorrect resource IDs being constructed.

Hi @VenkatV, Thank you for the comment. I fixed where you pointed out but there is still the same error.

You can try deploying the template through the Azure Portal, which may provide more detailed error messages or guidance.

It's not the error about arm template format, but the parameters you passed-in. I have simulated your template and print out the incoming value of your resource parameter.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env":{
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "dev"
            
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
        "resouceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "VMresouceGroupName": "rg-nonprod-japan-n01-test",
        "VMBackupSettings": {
            "dev": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01d",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2d"
            },
            "qa": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01t",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2t"
            },
            "stg": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01s",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2s"

            },
            "prod": {
                "instanceName": "VMshir01p",
                "backupVaultName": "az-rsv-nap-lrs-bkp01",
                "backupItemName": "iaasvmcontainerv2p"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[concat(variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupVaultName, '/Azure/vm;', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupItemName, ';', variables('resouceGroupName'),';', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
        },
        "friendlyName": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[concat(variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, 'BackupIntent')]"
        },
        "policyId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[concat('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies/', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].backupVaultName, '/EnhancedPolicy')]"
        },
        "sourceResourceId": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[resourceId(variables('subscriptionId'), variables('VMresouceGroupName'),'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('VMBackupSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
        }
    }
}

Which will print out what actually be passed-in, the result is:
Outputs :
   Name                Type                       Value
   ==================  =========================  ==========
   name                String                     "az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01/Azure/vm;iaasvmcontainerv2d;wb-test-once-rg;VMshir01d"
   friendlyName        String                     "VMshir01dBackupIntent"
   policyId            String                     "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies/az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01/EnhancedPolicy"
   sourceResourceId    String
                          "/subscriptions/069b5897-e6c2-496e-aa2b-7ccfaeeebd80/resourceGroups/rg-nonprod-japan-n01-test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VMshir01d"

If you compare the original rest api with the arm template, you will figure out that the policyId is passing incorrectly.

What the policyId needed to passed-in is a azure resource Id, But yours here is, it's not a azure resource id.
Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies/az-rsv-na-lrs-bkp01/EnhancedPolicy

